# Render chrome with PrintWindow

Tags: c, google-chrome, winapi

I am trying to get chrome to paint on my canvas using `PrintWindow`. Here is the code I use to render the desktop capture

```
PRECT lpRect;
GetWindowRect(g_Window, lpRect);

HDC hDeviceContext    =
   CreateCompatibleDC(g_DeviceContextMain);
HBITMAP hBitmapWindow = 
   CreateCompatibleBitmap(g_DeviceContextMain, lpRect->right - lpRect->left, lpRect->bottom - lpRect->top);

SelectObject(hDeviceContext, hBitmapWindow);
if (PrintWindow(g_Window, hDeviceContext, g_IsAtleast81 ? 0x00000002 : NULL)) {
    BitBlt(g_DeviceContextClient, 
       lpRect->left, lpRect->top, lpRect->right - lpRect->left, lpRect->bottom - lpRect->top, hDeviceContext, NULL, NULL, SRCCOPY);
}

DeleteObject(hBitmapWindow);
DeleteDC(hDeviceContext);
```

Here is the output when I open chrome and capture the screen (Windows 7)

[image: 1]

I can fix this in Windows 10 by adding the `PW_RENDERFULLCONTENT` flag to `PrintWindow` but unfortunately this flag is only available in Windows 8.1 and up. I need to get this to work in Windows 7/8.

I also tried disabling hardware acceleration in chrome, prior to capture the screen. The result was still the same!

Any way I can go about fixing this issue, such that the main window is drawn without a black rectangle? Or replicate what `PW_RENDERFULLCONTENT` does with Windows >= 8.1 in Windows < 8?

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't print the chrome window using PrintWindow, but what you may do is using [BitBlt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_blit). The function will only get parts of the screen, therefore you can't get the bitmap of a minimized window, unlike PrintScreen.

[BitBlt Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-bitblt)

and how it was implemented in webrtc:
https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/window_capturer_win.cc

Comment: This would be acceptable, however in my application the user can choose to monitor any Desktop on his computer. If we were talking about the current desktop like `WinSta0` then this answer would be acceptable. However, I cannot accept this, also I tried using `BitBlt` and it did not capture the screen if the Desktop is not the current one.

Comment: I'm trying to find the text in the question which imposes all extra restrictions. I can't see it. It's frustrating for answerers when this happens.